# I erased my MacBook and now can’t redownload macOS Big Sur, no free space

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, recovery

I did the basic erase hard drive on my computer but i didn’t do a time machine backup and now when i go into Recovery mode and try to reinstall macOS Big Sur it tells me there isn’t enough space on the disk and an additional 6.05 GB is needed. My model is a MacBook Pro 2019

[image]

Comment: What's a "basic erase?"  Can you give us a (general) overview of what you actually did?  An erase will wipe your drive and you should have ample space to install things.  Please respond with an [edit] to your original question.

Comment: Sorry i did the disk utility and selected my Macintosh HD drive and erased that entirely and when i go to reinstall macos Big sur there isn’t enough space and there’s a required 6 gb

Comment: I think you erased the "read-only" Macintosh HD volume, but not the rest of the disk. In Disk Utility menus: View > Show all devices (select this). Then you will see the drive - erase that. Nothing will be left - is the what you intended?

Answer (score 6):

Your Mac supports internet recovery. Take it to a network that lets you boot from the internet so you can follow Apple’s instructions on erasing all of the local disk.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904
- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208496 (your “basic erase” wording is confusing to me since this article shows how complicated things are with Intel / Apple Silicon / APFS and more - even for an expert - it's not so easy to erase a disk now. Specifically there should be no Data volumes as shown in your helpful screen image, so be sure you delete them - you need to erase **everything** before reinstalling.)

If you get an error that the disk is busy - that indicates you're not booted from the internet or you're not choosing the local disk to erase. Repeat the instructions and be sure you understand the details / choose the correct volumes - sometimes having someone help slow things down and watch the process helps. The documentation and process is for your exact scenario.

The only moderate complication is you want not the latest OS - so be sure to enter recovery with the following combination:

- Reinstall your computer’s original version of macOS (including available updates): [Press and hold Shift-Option-Command-R](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201255#guidelines).

If your Mac shipped earlier than Big Sur - it will install an older OS - complete that erase and install and then choose Big Sur to reinstall from this article:

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211683

The TLDR for this is:

- be sure you enter internet recovery for the original OS
- erase the disk entirely (all files will be gone)
- let the installer from internet recovery install the original OS
- upgrade to Big Sur (or other) as needed

Comment: I think part of the problem is that by default Disk Util hides the device & only shows the volumes. OP seems to have one  system volume [possibly now formatted from Internet Recovery] & *two* data volumes, but never erased the entire drive.

Answer (score 1):

Too much of your disk is used by other volumes, so there is indeed not enough space to download and install Big Sur. You need something like 40GB of free space in the install volume. You will need to delete some of the other volumes.

Comment: how do i do so without having any macos software installed?

Comment: @Dean Boot your Mac in Recovery mode and use Disk Utility there to repartition the disk. Instructions for using Recovery mode change from time to time -- search on Apple's website.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have large enough usb or external drive you can install macos on? if so do that, then boot into it. From their use disk utility completely erase the internal drive again. Then reinstall MacOS onto it. You may have only erased one of multiple partitions. Technically you can fully erase a HD while you are using that HD to do so.